# php artisan migrate error -could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, artisan-migrate

```
vadir@DESKTOP-6504PNT MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/lsapp
$ php artisan migrate
```

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
> could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema =
> lsapp and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
> at C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:671
> 667▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
> 668▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
> 669▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
> 670▕         catch (Exception $e) {
> ➜ 671▕             throw new QueryException(
> 672▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
> 673▕             );
> 674▕         }
> 675▕
> 1   C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception.php:18
> Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception::("could not find driver")
> 2   C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:41
> Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception::new()

Comment: check your `.env ` make sure correct database

Comment: Ive already checked. i've also tried all the methods and solutions that are answered to this similar question from years back. None of them are working. Php versions are also similar. Have something changed all of a sudden??

Comment: then it is driver issue change in `php.ini` then restart pc to effect

Comment: Please guide me what to edit in php.ini

Comment: Is there no  solution for this??